# Centering an element that has an aspect-ratio

Tags: html, css, aspect-ratio

I'm having a weird issue when trying to center an element that has aspect-ratio applied. I'd assume it would behave similarly to how centering an image works but I keep ending up with an element of 0px x 0px.

https://codepen.io/richardcool/pen/xxeKOwp

I have created a basic CodePen to show the issue. If I uncomment the `align-items: center` line then the element becomes 0px x 0px. I have also tried centering using absolute positions and get the same issue.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet** using the `<>` icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Aspect ratio requires either a definite height or width... a `max-x` isn't defined so it defaults to `auto` which is `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as there is no content in your div that determines the size, you have to specify either a width or a height when using `aspect-ratio` and `align-items: center`. For example like this:

```html
<div class="video">
  <div class="poster"></div>
</div>
```

```css
div.video {
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
div.poster {
    aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
    background-color: yellow;
    max-height: 60%;
    max-width: 60%;
    height: 60%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For aspect ratio to work properly with alignment like flex, you need to specify an actual `width` or `height` on the element, otherwise there is no base value for CSS to calculate with, even if you specify `max-width`.

Set the poster div to a width of 100%. Your max-width will override it, but then you’ll be able to vertically center it with `align-items: center` on the parent.